# A new Laravel project produces "SessionHandlerInterface not found"

Tags: laravel-5

I created a new Laravel 5.2 project and got stuck with the error:

```
local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Interface 'SessionHandlerInterface' not found in /pathto/theproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/FileSessionHandler.php:10
```

It is running on a freebsd-10.3 server with ngingx-1.10 and PHP 7.

The .env file contains:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=secret-key
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=secret-dbname
DB_USERNAME=secret-uname
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

All other files are untouched. What did I wrong?

PS: a new project with Laravel 5.1.33 works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution to the problem:

```
# pkg install php70-session
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this fixes the problem?

Comment: I installed php7 via pkg, apparently it was compiled with the flag --disable-session
[php_manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.installation.php)

Comment: Sadly, that did not work. The same error appeared. Should I reinstall php70 from the ports tree instead of ussing packages?

Comment: What would the new modules started to work, you must restart PHP

Comment: Works only after restarting `php-fpm` - `service php-fpm restart`